# Lower bound on trace of product of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, trace

I know there exists a Cauchy-Schwarz type upper bound for the trace of a product of matrices $A$ and $B$, but what about a lower bound?

Regarding the properties of the matrices $A$ and $B$ I am interested in: $A$ is a symmetric matrix, and $B$ has no special properties apart from the fact that it is a dense matrix with full rank and all of its elements are non-zero.

I would like to have a lower bound that separates $A$ and $B$, e.g., $$\text{Tr}(AB) \ge f(A)g(B)$$ for some functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: You may convert an upper bound of $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ into a lower bound by considering $\operatorname{tr}(-AB)$. Anyway, for real matrices, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives $\operatorname{tr}(AB)\ge-\|A\|_F\|B\|_F$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am looking for an inequality that allows me to show how the magnitude of $\text{Tr}(AB)$ can blow up if $A$ becomes singular. This is not possible with your inequality as even a very small positive $\text{Tr}(AB)$ will be greater than the right hand side if $A$ is almost singular.

Comment: For every matrix $A$, one can always find a $B$ such that $Tr(AB)=0$, so such an inequality is unlikely, unless $B$ is restricted to be 'non-perpendicular' to $A$.